# jdbc preparedstatement vs Resultset

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc

Can someone tell me the difference of using those two statement in jdbc. i try googling it and i still dont understand.

Comment: - [jdbc basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)  

 - [prepared statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: perhaps you haven't googled thorougly. Have a look at https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Statement-ResultSet-and-PreparedStatement-in-JDBC

Answer (score 0):

Google: [what is resultset in java](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=what+is+preparedstatement+in+java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=BTYCVtewNsa-0ASTrbWoAw#q=what+is+resultset+in+java)

[`ResultSet`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjABahUKEwjgiovss4zIAhUDKpQKHcEMCMQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Fsql%2FResultSet.html&usg=AFQjCNEblFlJ6Xml7H7of73BCeoJhgkrRg&bvm=bv.103388427,d.dGo) Documentation States that

> A table of data representing a database result set, which is usually generated by executing **a statement** that queries the database. A ResultSet object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of data. Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row.

**Note:** A **statement** refers to `PreparedStatement` in your case.